# R- character keyword exact search to dataframe

Tags: r, dataframe, search, keyword-search

input:

```
a <- c('a,a b,a b c,a b c d')
```

Like first word of character ie just "a" grep(search function) to another dataframe ie

```
df <- data.frame(rbind(c('a',1,'ewew'),c('a b c',101,'dffdhsd')))
```

and output in dataframe:

```
a,a b c
```

Comment: Not clear about the output.  Do you need `df[sapply(df, function(x) any(x %in% unlist(strsplit(a, ","))))]`

Comment: Not clear about the output.

Comment: Unable to get the output..
I meant i have 1 character vector and 1 data frame as inputs and have search each keyword from the character vector into particular column  if matched I store the matched words.
a <- c('a,a b,a b c,a b c d') AND df <- data.frame(rbind(c('a',1,'ewew'),c('a b c',101,'dffdhsd'),c('d f',405,'rtrtrtr')))
Desire Output should in this case will be both words in first column
a, a b c

Answer (score 0):

I'm not clear if this is your target, but you can try:

```
> ind <- apply(df, 1:2, function(x) x %in% strsplit(a, ",")[[1]])
> df[ind]
[1] "a"     "a b c"
```

Comment: Unable to get the output..
I meant i have 1 character vector and 1 data frame as inputs and have search each keyword from the character vector into particular column  if matched I store the matched words.
a <- c('a,a b,a b c,a b c d') AND df <- data.frame(rbind(c('a',1,'ewew'),c('a b c',101,'dffdhsd'),c('d f',405,'rtrtrtr')))
Desire Output should in this case will be both words in first column
a, a b c

Answer (score 0):

We split the 'a' by ',' into a `vector` and check whether `any` of the columns have those elements to create a logical vector for subsetting the columns

```
v1 <- unlist(strsplit(a, ","))
df[, sapply(df, function(x) any(x %in% v1))]
#[1] a     a b c
#Levels: a a b c
```

---

If we need to use `grep`, replace the `,` with `|` in 'a' and use that as `pattern`

```
pat <- gsub(",", "|", a)
```

Or

```
pat <- chartr(",", "|", a)
df[, colSums(sapply(df, grepl, pattern = pat)) > 1]
```

Comment: Unable to get the output..
I meant i have 1 character vector and 1 data frame as inputs and have search each keyword from the character vector into particular column  if matched I store the matched words.
a <- c('a,a b,a b c,a b c d') AND df <- data.frame(rbind(c('a',1,'ewew'),c('a b c',101,'dffdhsd'),c('d f',405,'rtrtrtr')))
Desire Output should in this case will be both words in first column
a, a b c